# Can I use my own biometric authentication to the autofill extension?

Tags: ios, autofill, biometrics, fido

Problem: The aim to the post is to find any way to use biometric verification(no system default) in autofill extension.

I've tried using ImagePicker, AVFoundation and AVCapture to open the camera, and I also tried using openUrl to open the main app to achieve my purpose. But in the end they all failed. I checked the document and found that autofill extension disabled these functions.

Is there any other way I can use my own biometric verification with autofill extension?